# Why use the void keyword?

Tags: javascript

I came across this snippet in [kriskowal/q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
/**
 * Applies the promised function in a future turn.
 * @param object    promise or immediate reference for target function
 * @param args      array of application arguments
 */
Q.fapply = fapply;
function fapply(value, args) {
    return dispatch(value, "apply", [void 0, args]);
}
```

What is the point of using the [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) keyword? Why not just write `[undefined, args]`?

Comment: Because global `undefined` can be redefined; it's not a reserved word, like `null`.

Comment: ..can be redefined, but starting in JavaScript 1.8.5, undefined is non-writable, as per the ECMAScript 5 specification.

Comment: `void 0` is 3 less characters than `undefined`.

Comment: Also useful as a hack to remove/reapply a CSS class: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: Can also be used in place of paranthesis to define an anonymous function as an expression (e.g., for IIFEs, `void function() { console.log("Look ma, no external paranthesis!"); }()`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [MDN Docs of void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> void expression
> ```
>
> **Uses**
>
> This operator allows inserting expressions that produce side effects
>   into places where an expression that evaluates to undefined is
>   desired.
>
> *The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined
>   primitive value*, usually using "void(0)" (which is equivalent to "void
>   0"). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead
>   (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

**And why?** See [MDN Undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

In older versions of JavaScript `undefined` could be overridden, but in starting in JavaScript 1.8.5, undefined is non-writable, as per the ECMAScript 5 specification.

Comment: Ok, so it's just a safer way of writing `undefined`?

Comment: yes, that is the reason.

Comment: @Rosarch: To be clear, the global `undefined` is non-writeable. You can still shadow it in a local variable scope. But make sure you don't allow any code to redefine `undefined`, and it's plenty safe to use.

Comment: ✅ you can void anything, it always returns undefined!
```js
void 0 === void(0);
// true

void 0 === void(true);
// true

void false === void(true);
// true
```
```js
void 0 === void(0);
// true

void 0 === void(true);
// true

void false === void(true);
// true
```

Answer (score 1):

The void is an important keyword in JavaScript which can be used as a unary operator that appears before its single operand, which may be of any type.

This operator specifies an expression to be evaluated without returning a value. Its syntax could be one of the  [following](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_void_keyword.htm)