# Prefixing a function call with void

Tags: javascript

I have come across this code:

```
return someFunctionThatReturnsAnArray()
  .map((action) => void dispatch(action))
  .run();
```

Can anyone suggest why you would prefix `void` in the map function so that it returns `undefined` each time?

Comment: looks like they don't know about `forEach`

Comment: Prefixing any function call with the `void` keyword discards the returned value.

Comment: Maybe `run()` **needs** an array of `undefined`, eh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use the void keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231601/why-use-the-void-keyword)

Comment: he knows what void means. reread the question.

Comment: `forEach` does not return an array so its not the same. What is more disturbing in this code it looks like they monkey patched `Array.prototype`  with `run` function.

Comment: yeah the answer appears to depend on adding the source of the magical `run()` function

Comment: at best the `run()` function could gather the length of the array from this. perhaps the programmer has an affinity for one line functions? the answers below amount to "i don't know" so i believe it shall remain a mystery.

Comment: Or maybe it's not an Array but something else with a map function that may have different semantics.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that's an array given that the function is called `someFunctionThatReturnsAnArray()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is essentially a clever way of defining a function that returns `undefined`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void):

> The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.

Your code is essentially the same as:

```
return someFunctionThatReturnsAnArray()
  .map((action) => { dispatch(action); })
  .run();
```

I'll be honest: if I came across that code in any project that I work with, I'd flag it for review. It doesn't really make sense and is potentially confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> `void` operator allows evaluating expressions that produce a value
>   into places where an expression that evaluates to undefined is
>   desired.

So it looks like :

- as long as the `dispatch` method is called, its return value is not important
- the result of the `map` method is an array with `undefined` values but its length is equal to the number of dispatched calls
- the `run` method is not standard for the **Array** prototype (seems like a custom patch), therefore it is hard to tell what it does.

One of its usage would be info of dispatched calls

```js
Array.prototype.run = function() {
  console.log("Dispatched calls : " + this.length);
};

var getArray = function() {
  return ['1', '2', '3'];
}

var dispatch = function(n) {
  return 10*n;
}

getArray().map((action) => void dispatch(action)).run();
```

Comment: But why would anyone need to discard the values of the array?

Comment: @BrunoEly I am not sure what was the author intention as the `run` method is not provided. One reason would be to indicate that `dispatch` method result is irrelevant and should not be used later on in the code??

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-void

> The void operator takes an operand and returns undefined: void
>   expression will evaluate expression and return undefined. It can be
>   used to ignore any side effects expression may produce:
>
> The common case of using void operator is to get a “pure” undefined
>   value as prior to ES5 the undefined variable was mutable:
>
> ```
> // will always return undefined
> (function(){
>     return void 0;
> })();
>
> // will return 1 in ES3 and undefined in ES5+
> (function(){
>     undefined = 1;
>     return undefined;
> })();
>
> // will throw TypeError in ES5+
> (function(){
>     'use strict';
>     undefined = 1;
> })();
> ```
>
> Another common case is to minify code as void 0 is shorter than
>   undefined:
>
> ```
> foo = void 0;
> foo = undefined;
> ```
>
> When used with IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression), void
>   can be used to force
>
> the function keyword to be treated as an expression instead of a
>   declaration:
>
> ```
> var foo = 1;
> void function(){ foo = 1; }() // will assign foo a value of 1
> +function(){ foo = 1; }() // same as above
> function(){ foo = 1; }() // will throw SyntaxError
> ```
>
> Some code styles prohibit void operator, marking it as non-obvious and
>   hard to read.

Can't see any good reason to be using it in the snippet that you have provided.